# Fundamental group of quotient of $S^1 \times [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have a past qual question here: Let $X = S^1 \times [0,1] /{\sim}$, where $(z,0) \sim (z^4,1)$ for $z \in S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \colon \| z \| = 1 \}$. Compute $\pi_1(X)$.

I've been trying to visualize $X$ as a cylinder of height 1 with the two ends identified `with a twist', but this has not seemed to help. Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried Van Kampen?

Comment: When you write $a\sim b$, the symbol $\sim$, since it represents a binary relation, has space before and after it.  When you write a quotient structure as $A/{\sim}$, you're not using it to say one thing is related to another, so it shouldn't have that spacing.  Then you code it as A/{\sim} rather than as A/\sim, so you see $A/{\sim}$ rather than $A/\sim{}$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can realize this space as a CW complex by attaching a $2$-cell to the wedge sum of two circles $\{a, b\}$ along the path $aba^{-4}b^{-1}$.