# Fundamental group of cylinder quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X = S^1 \times [0,1]$ be the cylinder, and define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $(z,1) \sim (iz,1)$.

What is the fundamental group of $X/\sim$?

Is $X$ the same as the mapping cylinder of $(z\mapsto z^4)$?

---

I found this in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887295/fundamental-group-of-the-quotient-of-a-cylinder-by-a-rotation-at-either-end). (The previous question had an additional rotation on the other end of the cylinder.) In a comment, the author concluded that $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_4$. But I keep getting a different solution! Using van Kampen on two ends of the cylinder (which intersect in the middle), I find that $\pi_1(X) = \langle a,b \rangle / \langle a^4b^{-1}\rangle = \langle a \rangle= \mathbb{Z}$.

Furthermore, a CW structure with:

- 2 points $p,q$
- 3 lines $a,b,c$ where $a$ is a loop at $p$, $b$ is a loop at $q$, and $c$ goes from $p$ to $q$
- 1 two-cell attached by boundary map $a^4cb^{-1}c^{-1}$

has $H_1=\mathbb{Z}$, which is not the abelianization of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is the mapping cylinder, so it is homotopy equivalent to a circle, and your result is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer of $\mathbb{Z}$ is correct. One way you may visualize this is that you "twisted" one end of the cylinder twice, each times covering it back again. Then the whole cylinder is extremely stretched, but the topology is still the same. Thus if you "untwist" everything you should recover a normal cylinder.

I suspect the other answer was written in [a different context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878826/fundamental-group-of-quotient-of-s1-times-0-1), namely if the two ends are identified together. In this case the fudamental group is $\langle a, b\rangle:aba^{-4}b^{-1}=1$. Thus its abelianization is $a^3=1$.

Comment: Thanks! So the answer to the [question I linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887295/fundamental-group-of-the-quotient-of-a-cylinder-by-a-rotation-at-either-end) would be the infinite-dimensional non-abelian gorup $\pi_1(X) = \langle a,b \mid a^4 = b^7 \rangle$ ? Is there any simpler way to express this group?

Comment: @anon: I could be wrong, but I am a bit confused with the other post. If the two ends are not identified, then what we have is a number of twists on both ends, which should not influence the fundamental group as we have seen. If the author meant both ends are identified, then I think the gluing argument is fine. But I am having trouble to see why $a^4=1$ and not $a^3=1$ in the abelianization. For the group you mentioned itself, I think even $\langle a,b|a^2=b^2\rangle$ is a quite complicated group already. I am not a geometric group theorist so I cannot comment further on this.